# How to add numbers to a two column tibble from a reference tibble?

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse, tibble

Here goes a question that has been troubling me for a while now and I am sure there is a solution to it but I do not seem to find a way to tackle it.

I have reached this point in my code where I have something similar to the toy tibbles I created below...

To this tibble

```
id_tibble <- tibble(
  color = c("blue", "orange", "orange", "orange", "yellow", "black"),
  animals = c("elephant", "tiger", "leon", "leopard", "hawk", "hawk")
  )
```

I want to add two columns "color_num" and "animals_num" with only "compatible" numbers from another tibble that looks like this

```
compatible_numbers <- tibble(
  key = c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 8), rep(3, 8), rep(4, 8), rep(5, 8), rep(6, 8), rep(7, 8)),
  main = c(seq(2, 9), seq(13, 20), seq(25,32), seq(3, 18, by =2), c(4, 6:12), seq(7, 14), seq(5, 26, by = 3))
  )
```

If number 1 would be the minimum number from a pool of numbers (available_numbers) (ranging from 1 to 32, in this case) then I assign it to "blue". The first compatible number from column main (number 2) should be assigned to the "elephant" and repeated if necessary. Then, since 2 is no longer available (in the available_numbers vector) I would need to select the following available number, 3, from the "key" column and assign it to "orange". The compatible numbers to 3 are 25,26,27 those will be assigned to "tiger", "leon", "leopard" and so on and so forth...

```
available_numbers <- seq_len(max(compatible_numbers))[seq_len(max(compatible_numbers)) %in% c(compatible_numbers$key, compatible_numbers$main)]
```

The desired outcome is the following tibble

```
outcome_tibble <- tibble(
  color = c("blue", "orange", "orange", "orange", "yellow", "black"),
  animals = c("elephant", "tiger", "leon", "leopard", "hawk", "hawk"),
  color_num = c(1,3,3,3,4,6),
  animals_num = c(2,25, 26, 27, 5,5)
)
```

Thank you for your help!

### **SOLUTION**:

Inspired by the for loop shared by @RonakShah I have built in some if statements to satisfy more conditions and consider both the animal and the color column repeated values.

Please, post any *tidyverse* version if you have one?

```
id_tibble$color_num <- NA
id_tibble$animals_num <- NA


for(i in 1:nrow(id_tibble)){
  if (i == 1){
    #assign the first available number
    id_tibble$color_num[i] <- available_numbers[1]
    all_num <- compatible_numbers$main[compatible_numbers$key == available_numbers[1]]
    #Keep only the ones which are available
    all_num <- intersect(all_num, available_numbers)
    #Remove the color_num value
    available_numbers <- available_numbers[-1]
    #assign the first available compatible number
    id_tibble$animals_num[i] <- all_num[1]
    #Remove the animal_num value
    available_numbers <- available_numbers[-1]
  } else{
    if(id_tibble$color[i] != id_tibble$color[i-1] && id_tibble$animals[i] != id_tibble$animals[i-1]){
      #assign the first available number
      id_tibble$color_num[i] <- available_numbers[1]
      all_num <- compatible_numbers$main[compatible_numbers$key == available_numbers[1]]
      #Keep only the ones which are available
      all_num <- intersect(all_num, available_numbers)
      #Remove the color_num value
      available_numbers <- available_numbers[-1]
      #assign the first available compatible number
      id_tibble$animals_num[i] <- all_num[1]
      #Remove the animal_num value
      available_numbers <- available_numbers[-which(available_numbers == all_num[1])]
    } else if(id_tibble$color[i] == id_tibble$color[i-1] && id_tibble$animals[i] != id_tibble$animals[i-1]){
      #assign the previous number
      id_tibble$color_num[i] <- id_tibble$color_num[i-1]
      all_num <- compatible_numbers$main[compatible_numbers$key == id_tibble$color_num[i-1]]
      #Keep only the ones which are available
      all_num <- intersect(all_num, available_numbers)
      #assign the first available compatible number
      id_tibble$animals_num[i] <- all_num[1]
      #Remove the animal_num value
      available_numbers <- available_numbers[-which(available_numbers == all_num[1])]
    } else if(id_tibble$color[i] != id_tibble$color[i-1] && id_tibble$animals[i] == id_tibble$animals[i-1]){
      #assign the previous number
      id_tibble$animals_num[i] <- id_tibble$animals_num[i-1]
      all_num <- compatible_numbers$main[compatible_numbers$key == id_tibble$animals_num[i-1]]
      #Keep only the ones which are available
      all_num <- intersect(all_num, available_numbers)
      #assign the first available compatible number
      id_tibble$color_num[i] <- all_num[1]
      #Remove the animal_num value
      available_numbers <- available_numbers[-which(available_numbers == all_num[1])]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is 5 repeated in the last column ?

Comment: @RonakShah 5 is assigned to "hawk" as it is repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a `for` loop solution for this -

```
id_tibble$color_num <- NA
id_tibble$animals_num <- NA

#run the loop only for unique values in color
for(uq in unique(id_tibble$color)) {
  #get row position for this color value
  i <- which(id_tibble$color == uq)
  #assign the first available number
  id_tibble$color_num[i] <- available_numbers[1]
  #Get corresponding values of the number
  all_num <- compatible_numbers$main[compatible_numbers$key == available_numbers[1]]
  #Keep only the ones which are available
  all_num <- intersect(all_num, available_numbers)
  #Remove the color_num value
  available_numbers <- available_numbers[-1]
  #assign the animals_num value
  id_tibble$animals_num[i] <- all_num[seq_along(i)]
  #Drop the values which are assigned in animals_num
  available_numbers <- setdiff(available_numbers, id_tibble$animals_num[i])
}

#  color  animals  color_num animals_num
#  <chr>  <chr>        <int>       <int>
#1 blue   elephant         1           2
#2 orange tiger            3          25
#3 orange leon             3          26
#4 orange leopard          3          27
#5 yellow hawk             4           5
#6 black  hawk             6           7
```

Comment: Hello @RonakShah Thank you for sharing your for loop but in your answer "hawk" is assigned a different number when it should be the same as the row above.